# \AtEndDocument causing spurious page break in exam class

Tags: page-breaking, exam

Please see the MWE below. This is rather simple. The `\AtEndDocument` is causing a spurious page break
before its execution. But the same code, when executed directly, does not cause this page break.

```
\documentclass{exam}

\AtEndDocument{%
  \vfill
  \begin{center}
    \textsc{== End of Questions ==}
  \end{center}}

\begin{document}


\begin{questions} 

  \question Test question 1 

  \question Test question 2

\end{questions}

% When inserted directly, it will not cause the page break

% \vfill
% \begin{center}
%   \textsc{== End of Questions ==}
% \end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

As Werner wrote, exam inserts code with `\AtEndDocument` too.
With a current LaTeX you can define a rule, so that your `enddocument` code is before the code from the class:

```
\documentclass{exam}

\AddToHook{enddocument}[myhook]{%
  \vfill
  \begin{center}
    \textsc{== End of Questions ==}
  \end{center}}

\DeclareHookRule{enddocument}{myhook}{before}{exam}
\begin{document}


\begin{questions}

  \question Test question 1

  \question Test question 2

\end{questions}

% When inserted directly, it will not cause the page break

% \vfill
% \begin{center}
%   \textsc{== End of Questions ==}
% \end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is `\AddToHook` alright? I am getting an undefined command error message.

Comment: Oh, I need the `lthooks` package.

Comment: No, further complications, `LaTeX Error: Command \AtBeginEnvironment already defined`.

Comment: At I wrote: this require a current latex, and also all other packages should be up-to-date. You should not load lthooks separately.

Comment: With older LaTeX you could more the \AtEndDocument before the \documentclass. But be aware that this won't work in a current LaTeX, there you really should use the rule declaration.

Comment: I think that I will resort to the manual method of adding the text at the end. If I add ` \AtEndDocument` before the `\documentclass`, that will mean perhaps my document will produce a different set of results when my LaTeX *really* gets upgraded to the latest one at the next upgrade of Ubuntu. Though, I am running the latest version of Ubuntu at this moment.

Answer (score 2):

The [`exam` class](//ctan.org/pkg/exam) already adds a `\clearpage` via `\AtEndDocument` as part of the class loading (starting with line 1737 in [`exam.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/exam/exam.cls)):

```
1737: \AtEndDocument{%
1738:   \clearpage
1739:   ...
```

While it doesn't print anything, the `\clearpage` is used to flush any remaining pages in order to calculate appropriate page references/counts. Since you issue an additional `\AtEndDocument` collection that is added *after* the `\clearpage` *and* prints content, it *will* reside on a new/separate page.